# Connecting two ports of arduino together

Tags: arduino, can, arduino-uno

I want to implement the working of a CAN transceiver using Arduino. But the problem is - I have only one Arduino. So, I thought of sending and receiving signals using different ports of the same Arduino. Is it practically possible?
PS: I have 2 CAN transceivers

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

Just connect them and for example see if you can receive back on one tranceiver what you send on the other one.

Comment: Do i need a resistor just in case?

Comment: @Helixxxx I don't know where you intend to put one so I can't say if you need one or not.

Comment: When we connect two pins of the same Arduino together, we need to restrict excess current flow ryt? So should i connect a resistor between two can CAN transcievers? (You may suggest some other place too)

Comment: Why would you connect two Arduino pins together? I think the purpose is to connect *different* Arduino pins to two *different*  CAN transceiver A and B ? It would help if you at least told which CAN transceivers they are, which interface they have and how you intend to connect them - I don't know any of that, I only know what you have written so far.